# Deploying Ecs with CodePipelin may fail and time out due to lack of CPU units

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

My configuration is to upload an Image from CircleCI to ECR, catch the changes in Codepipeline and deploy to ECS.

At that time, an error occurs when deploying to ECS.

```
service dev-test was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance xxxxxxxx has insufficient CPU units available. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section of the Amazon ECS Developer Guide.
```

I can expect that the task cannot be executed due to lack of CPU, but this error does not occur when deploying from CircleCI to ECS or deploying manually.
What is the solution to this problem?

Also, I don't know if this is related to this issue, but I have AutoScaling set to 2 for minimum and 4 for maximum, but AutoScaling is not running even though there is not enough CPU, and I get an error.
Is this problem also related to this issue?

**Container instance**

```
CPU: .5 vCPU
Memory: 3GB

CPU free space: 512
Free Memory: 769
```

**task_definition.json**

```
{
    "family": "development",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "nginx",
            "cpu": 512,
            "memoryReservation": 1024
        },
        {
            "name": "app",
            "cpu": 512,
            "memoryReservation": 1024
        },
        {
            "name": "aws-otel-collector",
            "cpu": 512,
            "memoryReservation": 1024
        }
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "1536",
    "memory": "3072",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    }
}
```

I have configured the cluster's capacity provider to resolve this issue.

```
Required size: 2
Minimum size: 2
Maximum size: 4
```

AutoScaling for the service is also set.

```
Minimum 2
Maximum 4
```

This results in two container instances being launched permanently.

With this setup, I had assumed that if there was not enough CPU at deployment time, a new container instance would be launched.

However, in reality, the error I mentioned earlier was displayed and there was no indication that a scale-out had taken place.

So several questions arose.

- Would capacity providers and AutoScaling not work during deployment?
- Would increasing the CPU capacity of each container instance solve this problem?
- Is it possible to temporarily increase CPU capacity only during deployment?

If anyone can help me understand this issue, please answer.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-event-messages.html#service-event-messages-1
I found a detailed error here, but it did not directly solve the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ECS Task` is too big and cannot fit on the EC2 instance. Try creating a new revision of the task with more CPU and memory

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I tried to check the ECS tasks, but where can I find the capacities, etc.?

Comment: If the task is too big, I don't understand how making the task even bigger is supposed to solve the problem.

Comment: Please confirm that we have changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I have AutoScaling set to 2 for minimum and 4 for maximum

This sounds like you have configured ECS Service autoscaling. The error is that you don't have an EC2 instance registered with the cluster that has available space to run the task. You need to configure a cluster [capacity provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-capacity-providers.html) with an EC2 auto-scaling group in order for ECS to automatically add EC2 instances to the cluster when they are needed.

Comment: I have set up a capacity provider but the problem is still not resolved.
I thought the scale out would happen on deployment as well, am I wrong?
By the way, as for setting up the capacity provider, I have configured the Auto Scaling group to be the Auto Scaling group created when the ECS cluster was created, with a capacity requirement of 2, minimum 2, maximum 4.

Comment: The capacity provider should scale out during deployments

Comment: Merged questions.
Sorry for my lack of understanding.
I understand that capacity providers are scaled out when deployed, but is the only way to do that is to set up a capacity provider on the cluster?
Just to add to my question, I have set up a capacity provider, but the error message is still the same as before.
Is there anything else that needs to be set up?

Comment: Do you have managed scaling turned on? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-auto-scaling.html

Comment: Thank you very much.
However, I thought that managed scaling did not have to be set if the capacity provider was created after May 27, 2022, am I mistaken?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-auto-scaling.html#update-ecs-resources-cas